# How can I extend the iPhone call log to have more than 100 entries?

Tags: iphone, ios

After some calls, the earlier call records are deleted from the iPhone. My system has at least 50-60 gigabytes free space, so there should be enough room for more entries.

How can I extend the call log for more than 100 entries?